# Change Firefox user agent permanently without Add-ons

Tags: windows, firefox, user-agent

According this article [How to reset the default user agent on Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-reset-default-user-agent-firefox), the procedure for changing user agent is to add a string value with `general.useragent.override` in `about:config` page.

But when I add the user agent string with `general.useragent.override`, it shows `modified` at the status column. The `modified` status preferences can be easily changed. While the status is `default` for other in-build preferences.

**How can I change the user agent so that it shows `default` status? Or How can I change user agent permanently?**

[image: Modified_Firefox_Useragent]

Comment: If the locking the answer below provides isn't what you want, edit the source and rebuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this article [Deploying Firefox in an enterprise environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment), first create a `autoconfig.js` file in `defaults\perf` folder Firefox program directory i.e. `C:\Program Files\Firefox\defaults\pref`. Write the following lines in that file.

```
// Must start with a comment!
pref("general.config.filename", "mozilla.cfg");
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
```

Then create `mozilla.cfg` file in Firefox program directory i.e. `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` and write the following lines in that file. `lockPref` will lock that preference and `defaultPref` will make it default. Put any user agent in place of `My_User_Agent`.

```
// Must start with a comment!
lockPref("general.useragent.override", "My_User_Agent");
```

Now restart Firefox to apply that change.

[image: Locked_User_Agent]