# Tricking website that you are using different browser or OS

Tags: mac, browser, privacy

For example when I look under recent logins on my gmail account or other websites it shows exact OS that I am using and exact Browser. Is there a way to change what Information I am sharing with website **without** any **browser extensions** or **software** on Mac OS?

Comment: What browser are you using? Some browsers allow you to override the default "User Agent" string that tells the server what browser is sending the request.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a different browser agent, I am sure, Safari supports doing this on MacOS

Comment: @Worthwelle thank you! I did this with chrome, however it goes back to normal when I refresh the page, is there a way to make it permanent ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Here's an overview how to change the user agent specification (which tells the website which browser you are using) on the different browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox): [look here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/01/16/change-user-agent-chrome-safari-firefox/). Depending on which browser you want to apply it to, just look for an up to date description for the current version. Like [this permanent one](https://superuser.com/questions/1283381/change-firefox-user-agent-permanently-without-add-ons) for Firefox.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill the essential part is that it can be done by changing the "user agent specification". there are multiple pages on the internet on how to do it for the different browsers